# Une « pédagogie » à faire auprès de quelqu'un ?

Tags: sens, formulation-idiomatique, politique

> « Ce n'est pas un sujet qui est sexy à vendre au Québec », reconnaît
>   M. Rayes, qui dit qu'il y aura de la « pédagogie » à faire à ce sujet
>   auprès des Québécois. ([Lapresse.ca](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/201904/26/01-5223733-les-conservateurs-sinspirent-de-la-caq-pour-conquerir-le-quebec.php))

---

Pour comprendre le contexte, il s'agit de propos d'un ténor de la droite canadienne qui veut à tout prix construire un autre pipeline au Québec pour assurer des débouchés au pétrole de son parti dont le château-fort est l'Alberta, en contexte de surproduction, menant inévitablement un pays avec une des pires fiches en ce qui a trait à la pollution *per capita* (le Canada) à manquer à ses obligations internationales (Paris) en ratant par une plus grande marge encore ses objectifs en matières d'émissions de GES. Ce laquais conservateur fait-il preuve de condescendance en assimilant les Québécois à des enfants crédules, quel genre de pédagogue encouragerait-il ces « enfants » à perpétuer leurs mauvaises habitudes et à polluer davantage, ou s'est-il simplement fourvoyé en parlant de « [pédagogie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/p%C3%A9dagogie) » *à faire*, ou est-ce dans la bouche de ce genre d'apologiste de [*faits alternatifs*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alternative_fact#Translations) une « alternative linguistique » pour autre chose complètement ?

---

Dans un contexte où l'on est assuré qu'il n'y a aucun savoir crédible ne s'appuyant sur aucune méthode ni science qui ne sera transmis à l'interlocuteur, peut-on parler de *pédagogie à faire* auprès de quelqu'un ; quelle formulation/expression avec *pédagogie* était de mise ici, que voudrait-elle dire ici ou autrement vu le contexte quel(s) mot(s) s'y substituerai(en)t plus clairement ?

Answer (score 1):

En politique, il y a toujours un décalage entre le mobile et le discours. Je fais de la pédagogie, mes adversaires font de la propagande. Je manifeste pour gagner plus d'argent au nom de la justice, les autres veulent gagner plus d'argent par cupidité. Le choix du terme tient à la posture qu'on veut montrer plus qu'à la réalité.

Comment: Assurément. Mais je m'intéresse davantage à la langue même si je me donne une grande liberté dans la rédaction de la question. Je t'invite à parler davantage directement de la locution avec « pédagogie ». D'abord qu'est-ce que « faire de la pédagogie » dans ce contexte, pourquoi pas avoir dit « éduquer » ou avoir parlé _d'éducation à faire_ ? Ensuite te vient-il à l'esprit une autre formulation avec pédagogie qui est plus courante quand l'interlocuteur est rébarbatif à l'enseignement, vu la phrase qui précède dans la citation etc.